# Match wildcard domain except two specific subdomains in HAproxy

Tags: haproxy

I have a rule which looks like this:

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if { hdr_end(Host) -i mydomain.live otherdomian.org } !{ ssl_fc }
```

But I want the rule to ignore sub1.otherdomain.org and sub2.otherdomain.org

I wanted to do something like:

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if { hdr_end(Host) -i mydomain.live otherdomian.org } unless { hdr_beg(host) -i sub1 sub2 } !{ ssl_fc }
```

but my syntax is not correct and I guess I just need to combine if and unless somehow.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks added for clarity:

```
redirect scheme https code 301 
  if { hdr_end(Host) -i .mydomain.live .otherdomian.org } 
     !{ hdr_beg(host) -i sub1 sub2 } 
     !{ ssl_fc }
```

In common language, the condition is this:

```
if (a) and (not (b)) and (not (c))
```

`if` and `unless` can only be used at the beginning of the expression.

Comment: Side note: I have always written my conditional expressions based on the belief that HAProxy evaluates these from left-to-right with short-circuiting behavior, so I place the conditions requiring the least amount of work, or that are most likely to be false, closer to the left.  Here, `!{ ssl_fc }` should probably be first, since there is no reason to examine the `Host` header when the frontend-connection is already known to be using SSL (TLS).  Any time saved by this approach generally seems unmeasurable, but if more computationally-intensive fetches or converters were used, it could add up.

Answer (score 0):

```
acl a1 hdr_beg(host) -i sub1.otherdomain.org sub2.otherdomain.org
acl a2 hdr_end(Host) -i mydomain.live otherdomain.org
redirect scheme https code 301 if !a1 a2
```